# STS 3.5.0 RELEASE Keeps Crashing

Tags: spring-tool-suite

My `STS 3.5.0 RELEASE`(64 bit) keeps crashing always.

**Currently using**

> - OS : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit)
> - JAVA : jdk 1.7.0_55

Any solution?

Comment: Do you see any crash logs or something like that? We've seen some crashes in STS/GGTS due to native libs on Linux in combination with the browser technology that we use, but a crash log would help to identify what is going on. Also please feel free to file a bug at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS.

Comment: @MartinLippert 
Couldn't find any unusual in log.

`[debug] execute contextualize
[debug] execute contextualize
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
[debug] execute contextualize
Aug 19, 2014 4:15:08 PM 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect`

Comment: what does the Error Log view in STS/Eclipse say? And is there a crash log in the STS (or configuration) directory?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've fixed it yet, but this was resolved on my machine by changing my GTK theme to something other than oxygen-gtk. If it's the same issue I had, STS will crash every time it tries to open a new modal window (such as the new project window).

Settings for this can be found in:
System Settings > Application Appearance > GTK

It seems that only the GTK2 theme needs to be updated to prevent the crashing. If it's not this, then please add more details to your original question.